# How to stop execution of command from prompt in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, prompt

My prompt contains some info about git repo under current directory. When I do `cd` somewhere, my shell executes some commands (i.e. `git status`).

Is there a way to stop execution of such commands via the same terminal? Sending signals from keyboard (e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) doesn't work.

#### Update #1

I don't want to disable those commands permanently - I just want them to start running and then stop them in runtime.

Comment: Depends on what you use to run the commands, do you have some alias for `cd`, or do you run them from `PROMPT_COMMAND` or ... Remove the commands where they were originally added.

Comment: Do you mean git status is performed as part of your PS1 variable? If so, you could use a function to swap between two options maybe

Answer (score 0):

those commands are child processes of the shell in some form.  if you `pstree -p $$` that will list the processes running under your shell at the moment.  you can then run a kill command which the same as Ctrl-C (SIGINT).  Here is an example with a manually background command, but it should be the same for your prompt update.  As an explanation the `$$` is pstree is a substitute for the process id of the shell, and pstree will display all process in a parent/child relationship, and the -p option limits it to your current shell.  Of course don't kill your shell pid, just the child you want to kill.

```
$ find / 2> /dev/null > /dev/null &
[1] 916595
$ pstree -p $$
bash(915332)─┬─find(916595)
             └─pstree(916598)
$ kill 916595
[1]+  Terminated              find / 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
$
`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
PS1='$(set -x; sleep 3; echo STATUS)$ '
```

You'll see that `^C` works. It's just that then bash tries to redraw a prompt and runs `sleep 3` again.

Same goes in:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='git_status=$(set -x; sleep 3; echo STATUS)' PS1='$git_status$ '
```

That can be worked around with:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
  interrupted=0
  trap interrupted=1 INT QUIT
  git_status=$(set -x; sleep 3; echo STATUS)
  trap - INT QUIT
  if (( interrupted )); then
    git_status+="<INTERRUPTED>"
  fi'
PS1='$git_status$ '
```

Where we add a handler on SIGINT. As the signal is handled and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` finishes normally, bash doesn't redraw the prompt. We can also add information that the command was interrupted in the prompt.

You'd replace `set -x; sleep 3; echo STATUS` here used as an example place holder with your `git status` or equivalent.

---

In zsh, you'd do something similar and a bit more cleanly with:

```
precmd() {
  set -o localoptions -o localtraps
  local interrupted=0
  trap interrupted=1 INT QUIT
  psvar[1]=$(set -x; sleep 3; echo STATUS)
  if (( interrupted )) psvar[1]+='<INTERRUPTED>'
}
PS1='%1v$ '
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using bash (echo $0 to see)?  If `cd` is not aliased to something else (try `unalias cd` or `unset cd`), then I suspect something in your shell's startup is causing this behavior.  On bash, this could be in .profile, .bashrc, or system bashrc.  On [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/48179), the advice is to use `--noprofile --norc` either when ssh'ing into a box, or when just invoking a new terminal from e.g., within your existing terminal.  So,

- Start as just `sh` which invokes Bash without .bashrc.  You can do this from within your "errant" terminal session
- `ssh -t foo@bar.com` and `-t` will bypass bashrc (have not tried)
- `ssh foo@bar.com bash --noprofile --norc` sounds safer (have not tried)

Comment: I don't want to get rid of prompt commands - I want to debug them in some way. I want to stop them while they're already executing.

Comment: Can you create your own "git" shell script, perhaps in $HOME/bin, that has a `read nonsense` command right before calling `/usr/bin/git $*`?  Something like `echo "press enter to continue" ; read nonsense ; /usr/bin/git $*` which gives you the chance to ^C out of it.

Comment: There is no point in such scenario - I want to set prompt command, run it, see some results, and stop it if needed. I.e. I may by mistake setup an infinite loop - and I want to break it without closing terminal, shell, losing all environment, etc.

Comment: If you can modify your prompt variable (PS1), you could add a delayed kill to guarantee termination of the command, hung or otherwise: `( sleep 12 ; echo 'my command output' ) & sleep 10 && kill $! &>-` The stuff in parens would be whatever your git command is.  You could use `kill -9 $!` to ensure that it stops.  The `&>-` suppresses the error message from `kill` in the event that the command completed.  But... what if that command finishes first, the above will make you wait the full 10 seconds.  Let me think on that.

Comment: Okay, couple of answers.  First, [read this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068).  Very useful.  Alternatively, you can use the `timeout` command, but I just tried it and my version of it does not accept the `-k` command, because apparently `getopts` was not used correctly.  Information on `timeout` [is in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10225072/8542716).